# mydomainname.com not working with https

Tags: apache, https, ssl-certificate

I have created a self signed SSL Certificate for testing purpose and I have configured the generated certificate at my virtual hosts file. But when I tried to access my domain  with https://mydomainname.com it's not working. Mozilla gives the error page

> Firefox can't establish a connection
>   to the server at mydomainname.com.

I have a Windows Vista machine and my virtual hosts file is following:

my vitual hosts file:

```
<IfDefine SSL>
 <VirtualHost mydomainname.com:80>
       #ServerName www.mydmainnamw.com:8080
       #DocumentRoot "C:/.../My Company/My Sites/johnbokma.com/site/web"
       #CustomLog logs/lc.johnbokma.com.access.log combined
       #ErrorLog logs/lc.johnbokma.com.error.log

       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile C:/Program Files (x86)/ApacheSoftwareFoundation/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt 
       SSLCertificateKeyFile C:/Program Files (x86)/ApacheSoftwareFoundation/conf/ssl.key/server.key

       SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
       CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
       "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

 </VirtualHost>
<IfDefine SSL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled ssl and listen to the right port?

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 443
SSLEngine On
```

You should use the default port for https (443)
Your virtual host should look something like this, (uncomment the servername part)

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName mydomainname.com
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. I have tried this but not working. please reply me another solution.

Comment: @Lokesh I updated with some more notes, you should also use * in your VirtualHost tag

Comment: Hi, actually I forget to listen my apache to 443 port. But now I make this changes and listen my apache to 443 port. But still I am stuck, now I get the error "SSL received a record that exceeded maximum permissible length. (Error code:ssl_error_rx__record_too_long)" please reply me for these solution if you know. thank you.

Comment: @Lokesh It seems that the SSL Engine is not activated on port 443.